# How to count occurrences of each key in list of dictionaries efficiently?

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

I want to count the occurrences of positive/negative document frequency for each token.  But my python script is running and running for the whole morning.Could you tell me what is wrong with something? Appreciated in advance.

```
import numpy as np
positive_feature=[[{'a':2,'b':1},1],
                  [{'b':2,'c':1},1]
                 ]

negative_feature=[[{'e':2,'b':1},0]
                 ]
alltokens=['a','b','c','e']

dic=dict((t,i) for i,t in enumerate(alltokens))

vacabulary_size=len(dic)

positive_doc_frequency,negative_doc_frequency=np.zeros(vacabulary_size), np.zeros(vacabulary_size)

for t in alltokens:
    for x in positive_feature:
        if t in x[0].keys():
            positive_doc_frequency[dic[t]]+=1
    for x in negative_feature:
        if t in x[0].keys():
            negative_doc_frequency[dic[t]]+=1
```

According to the element order of alltokens list, I want to the positive_doc_frequency/negative_doc_frequency is like as:

```
alltokens=['a','b','c','e']
positive_doc_frequency=[1,2,1,0]
negative_doc_frequency=[0,1,0,1]
```

but the python script is still running now,(from 8:00AM to 4:00PM) ,Any optimization for my script? Thanks again.

**UPDATE:**
The question is misleading because of poor sample data. Let me correct it.

Input:

```
alltokens=['a','b','c','e']
positive_feature=[[{'a':aa,'b':bb},1],
                  [{'b':vv,'c':cc},1]
                 ]

negative_feature=[[{'e':ee,'b':bb},0]
                 ]
```

Output I want to is :

```
positive_doc_frequency=[1,2,1,0]
negative_doc_frequency=[0,1,0,1]
```

1,2,1,0 in positive_doc_frequency list stands for 'a' occurs one time in positive_feature list, 'b' occurs two times , 'c' occurs one time ,'e' occurs zero times in positive_feature list.

Comment: How has this code possibly been running for 8 hours?

Comment: Are you sure it was running for that length of time?  I would put in some print statements so that way you can then monitor where you are better.  @EliSadoff My bet is that OP is just giving sample data and not is actual information set.

Comment: It is not running that long , it just completed the script and exited, just add print statement and you will get the output `print(positive_doc_frequency)` `print(negative_doc_frequency)`

Comment: @Eli Sadoff  believe it or not， I omit a little code for simplification. I have 12500 positive/negative document .  Fallenreaper,  your assumption is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d for d, x in positive_feature))
print(*sorted(c.items()))
```

This makes a list of all the keys in `positive_feature`, then counts how many of each key there are, then prints the counts.

To get the counts like you want them, do

```
pos_freq = [c[key] for key in alltokens]
```

Comment: Hi, there is TypeError: 'method_descriptor' object is not iterable in the last line.

Comment: @KevinAuds oops, didn't call it.  That should be `Counter.items()` not `Counter.items`

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'items' of 'dict' object needs an argument. Dear Patrick, Have you seen my update for the original question?

Comment: @KevinAuds another dumb mistake.  I was calling an instance method like a class method, which doesn't work.

Comment: The code snippet is excellent and saves me more running time.There is some advanced trick for python newbie,I will learn it following your code hint.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @KevinAuds `chain.from_iterable` looks complicated, but it's really not.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code would have ran for that length of time, even with a large data set.

There are many ways to [count occurrences of things](http://treyhunner.com/2015/11/counting-things-in-python/) in Python. I [performance tested](https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/0987601f960a5617a1be) a few different techniques and found that [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html) in the standard library was the fastest approach (not surprisingly since it's optimized just for this use case).

Using `collections.Counter` with your code would look something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

positive_doc_frequency = Counter()
negative_doc_frequency = Counter()

for t in alltokens:
    for x in positive_feature:
        positive_doc_frequency.update(x[0].keys())
    for x in negative_feature:
        negative_doc_frequency.update(x[0].keys())
```